# Eclipse shortkey for termination Application Server and GWT development mode

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt, jakarta-ee, gwt2

I need a shortkey to terminate my application server and another for GWT development mode, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Break</kbd> is not working! I don't know why.

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

By default, the key is <kbd>⌘+F2</kbd> (on Mac). I'm not sure on Windows, but you can check and/or change it by going to `Preferences -> General -> Keys` and typing `Terminate` in the filter box. You want the first option (Terminate).